# Hexadecimal user rep

Tags: script, reputation

### About

Displays user reputation in hexadecimal. The code is quite simple if you want to do any tweaks. For users with rep >= 0x10000, it switches the font to Arial Narrow to prevent breaking layouts.

#### Download

[Install](https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/source/68543.user.js) | [View source](https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/68543)

#### Platform

Tested on Firefox 4.0 and Chrome 10.0, on Windows 7. Requires Greasemonkey on Firefox.

#### License

Do whatever you want, as long as you don't sell it or claim you wrote it. If you make any cool modifications, let me know!

#### Source

It seems that userscripts.org is dying. Here is the code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           hex stack overflow rep
// @namespace      stackoverflow
// @description    Displays user's rep in hexadecimal on stack overflow
// @include       http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http://superuser.com/*
// @include       http://meta.superuser.com/*
// @include       http://serverfault.com/*
// @include       http://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @include       http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include       http://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @include       http://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include       http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include       http://nothingtoinstall.com/*
// @include       http://meta.nothingtoinstall.com/*
// @include       http://seasonedadvice.com/*
// @include       http://meta.seasonedadvice.com/*
// @include       http://crossvalidated.com/*
// @include       http://askdifferent.com/*
// @include       http://meta.crossvalidated.com/*
// @include       http://stackapps.com/*
// @include       http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://api.*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://area51.stackexchange.com/*
// @author         Kip Robinson - http://stackoverflow.com/users/18511/kip
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
   function with_jquery(f) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }; 

  with_jquery(function($)
  {
    $('.reputation-score').each(function() {
      var title = $(this).attr('title');
      var text = $(this).text();
      var rep = 1;

      if(text.indexOf('k') < 0)
      {
        rep = parseInt(text.replace(/,/g, ''));
      }
      else
      {
        rep = parseInt(title.replace(/\D/g, ''));

        //if no rep was in the tooltip, convert the truncated rep to hex
        if(isNaN(rep))
          rep = Math.round(1000 * parseFloat(text.replace(/[k,]/gi, '')));
      }

      $(this).text('x' + rep.toString(16).toUpperCase());
      if(rep >= 0x10000)
        $(this).css('font-family', 'Arial Narrow,' + $(this).css('font-family'));
    });
  });

})();
```

Comment: useless AND I LOVE IT!

Comment: I believe "useless" would be an understatement, but like many useless things, it's quite humorous. :)

Comment: @Kip See [Octal user reputation](http://stackapps.com/q/3967/14487), a derivative of this script.

Answer (score 5):

Nice script! I modified your script slightly to obtain a script that does not show exact reputation but just category of the user. It can easily be modified to show symbols in place of the numbers:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           hex stack overflow rep
// @namespace      stackoverflow
// @description    Displays user's rep in hexadecimal on stack overflow
// @include       http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http://superuser.com/*
// @include       http://meta.superuser.com/*
// @include       http://serverfault.com/*
// @include       http://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @include       http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include       http://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @include       http://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include       http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include       http://nothingtoinstall.com/*
// @include       http://meta.nothingtoinstall.com/*
// @include       http://seasonedadvice.com/*
// @include       http://meta.seasonedadvice.com/*
// @include       http://crossvalidated.com/*
// @include       http://askdifferent.com/*
// @include       http://meta.crossvalidated.com/*
// @include       http://stackapps.com/*
// @include       http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://api.*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://area51.stackexchange.com/*
// @author         Kip Robinson - http://stackoverflow.com/users/18511/kip
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  function with_jquery(f) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }; 

  with_jquery(function($) {
    $('.reputation-score').each(function() {
      var title = $(this).attr('title');
      var text = $(this).text();
      var rep = 1;

      if(text.indexOf('k') < 0) {
        rep = parseInt(text.replace(/,/g, ''));
      } else {
        rep = parseInt(title.replace(/\D/g, ''));

        //if no rep was in the tooltip, convert the truncated rep to hex
        if(isNaN(rep))
          rep = Math.round(1000 * parseFloat(text.replace(/[k,]/gi, '')));
      }

      if(rep >= 20000) $(this).text('20K+');       // 'Trusted'
      else if(rep >= 10000) $(this).text('10K+');  // 'Moderator'
      else if(rep >= 3000) $(this).text('3K+');    // 'Scope Definer' 'Closer'
      else if(rep >= 2000) $(this).text('2K+');    // 'Editor'
      else if(rep >= 1000) $(this).text('1K+');    // 'Expert'
      else if(rep >= 500) $(this).text('500+');    // 'Retagger'
      else if(rep >= 200) $(this).text('200+');    // 'Contributer'
      else if(rep >= 50) $(this).text('50+');      // 'Commentator'
      else if(rep >= 15) $(this).text('15+');      // 'Voter'
      else $(this).text('!');                      // 'New'

//    if(rep >= 0x10000)
//      $(this).css('font-family', 'Arial Narrow,' + $(this).css('font-family'));
    });
  });

})()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one which hides vote counts and only shows range:

---

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           se symb votes
// @namespace      stackoverflow
// @description    Displays vote counts symbolicly on SE network
// @include       http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http://superuser.com/*
// @include       http://meta.superuser.com/*
// @include       http://serverfault.com/*
// @include       http://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @include       http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include       http://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @include       http://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include       http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include       http://nothingtoinstall.com/*
// @include       http://meta.nothingtoinstall.com/*
// @include       http://seasonedadvice.com/*
// @include       http://meta.seasonedadvice.com/*
// @include       http://crossvalidated.com/*
// @include       http://askdifferent.com/*
// @include       http://meta.crossvalidated.com/*
// @include       http://stackapps.com/*
// @include       http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://api.*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://area51.stackexchange.com/*
// @author          
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  function with_jquery(f) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }; 

  with_jquery(function($) {
    $('.vote-count-post').each(function() {
      var title = $(this).attr('title');
      var text = $(this).text();
      var vote = 0;

      if(text.indexOf('k') < 0) {
        vote = parseInt(text.replace(/,/g, ''));
      } else {
        vote = parseInt(title.replace(/\D/g, ''));

    //if no vote was in the tooltip, convert the truncated vote to hex
        if(isNaN(vote))
          vote = Math.round(1000 * parseFloat(text.replace(/[k,]/gi, '')));
      }

      if(vote >= 100) $(this).text('100+');      
      else if(vote >= 25) $(this).text('25+'); 
      else if(vote >= 10) $(this).text('10+');  
      else if(vote >= 1)  $(this).text('+');  
      else if(vote >= 0)  $(this).text('0');
      else $(this).text('-');

    });
  });

})()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to have decimal number next to it, or in a tooltip. Is this possible?

Comment: To show original rep in a tooltip, after `$(this).text(....);`, you would add: `$(this).attr('title', rep);`

Comment: to show it next to it might mess up layout, but you would just append it to the string argument passed to `$(this).text(....);`.  Something like:  `$(this).text('x' + rep.toString(16).toUpperCase() + ' - ' + rep.toString());`

Comment: In a tooltip you could chain it together `$(this).text(....).attr('title',rep);` and use one statement instead of two

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS support, changes your own rep in the top bar as well.

Great script btw :D

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           hex stack overflow rep
// @namespace      stackoverflow
// @description    Displays user's rep in hexadecimal on stack overflow
// @include       http*://*stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http*://*superuser.com/*
// @include       http*://*serverfault.com/*
// @include       http*://*askubuntu.com/*
// @include       http*://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include       http*://*stackapps.com/*
// @author         Kip Robinson
// ==/UserScript==

!function() {
   function with_jquery(f) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }; 

  with_jquery(function() {
    function calculate(x){
      var title = $(x).attr('title'),
      text = $(x).text(),
      rep = 1;

      if(text.indexOf('k') < 0){rep = parseInt(text.replace(/,/g, ''));}
      else{
        rep = parseInt(title.replace(/\D/g, ''));

        //if no rep was in the tooltip, convert the truncated rep to hex
        if(isNaN(rep)) rep = Math.round(1000 * parseFloat(text.replace(/[k,]/gi, '')));
      }

      $(x).text('0x' + rep.toString(16).toUpperCase()).attr('title',rep);
    }
    $('.-rep').each(function() {
      calculate(this);
    });
    $('.reputation-score').each(function() {
      calculate(this);
    });
  });

}();
```