# Bold and colorful area tags

Tags: script, tags

#### About:

This script is written for [cstheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) and [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/). It modifies the way the area tags (tags having . in their names) are displayed.

The script is based on [Hexadecimal user rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/2342/hexadecimal-user-rep/2496#2496).

#### Download:

[Install](http://www.userscripts.org/scripts/source/111862.user.js) | [View source](https://www.userscripts.org/scripts/review/111862)

#### Changelog:

1.1:

- Added two more tags to area tags (quantum-computing, computability)
- You can now also show meta-tags in a different color

1.0:

- The first version

#### Screenshot

[image: screen shot]

Comment: uncomment the lines for Meta-Tags to also get a different color for meta-tags. You can easily add other tags to the lists.