# Octal user reputation

Tags: script

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

### About

Displays reputation in octal. This script is derived from [Kip's](https://stackapps.com/u/5418) [Hexadecimal user rep](https://stackapps.com/q/2342/14487).

#### Download

[Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/156771.user.js) | [View Source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/156771)

#### Platform

Firefox 19.0.1 with Greasemonkey

#### License

Same as the original. Do whatever you want, as long as you don't sell it or claim you wrote it. If you make any cool modifications, let me know!

Comment: cool. In C/Java octal numbers are usually indicated by a leading `0` though

Comment: @Kip I omitted it to save space since most of the numbers require more digits than their decimal equivalents.